# Differential equation finding limit without solving explicitly.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

The weight w(t) of an individual  fish at time t is governed by the differential equation.

$ \frac{dw}{dt} = \alpha w^{2/3}-\beta w $

with initial condition $ w(0) = w_{0} $ ( the weight at birth) and where $ \alpha$ and $ \beta$ are positive parameters depending on the fish species.  Without solving the differential equation, determine

$$ \lim_{t\to \infty} w(t)$$
I am not sure how to analyse this without solving? Maybe graph it, but I am not even sure how to start that, any help help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\frac{dw}{dt} = w^{2/3}(\alpha - \beta w^{1/3}),$ so if $w^{1/3} = \alpha/\beta$, then $\frac{dw}{dt} = 0$ for all $t$, so the graph of the solution with $w(0) = (\alpha/\beta)^3$ will be a horizontal line.

If $w(0) > (\alpha/\beta)^3$ then $\frac{dw}{dt} <0$ by looking at the first equation I wrote.  So the graph of that solution is decreasing.

Likewise, if $w(0) < (\alpha/\beta)^3$ then $\frac{dw}{dt} >0$, and the graph is increasing.  So no matter what the initial condition, the graph of the solution will be asymptotic to the horizontal line above.  That makes your limit $(\alpha/\beta)^3.$

Comment: Thank you for this explanation ^^

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**  Find the critical points of this ODE and then draw the [Phase Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_line_(mathematics)). Then, classify the critical points as attractors, repellors or shunts so that you can see the behaviour qualitatively.

Comment: how would I know if this is a cubic graph or a quadratic ?

Comment: It wouldn't be either - what does your autonomous ode look like that you want to solve?